# Hosting MP3 files in rails without auto downloading them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mp3, rails-activestorage

Im building an API and I need to host MP3 files.

I have used active storage to upload the MP3 files and that all works fine, however when I create an endpoint with a url to the MP3 file, that URL just downloads the MP3 file rather than taking me to a page where I can listen to it.

Im trying to replicate the behaviour seen here:

[MP3 link](https://cdn.thebetterappcompany.com/media/life_made_better/HcjUPqiwHmmwfJQYcYQZmEebN5rEXVrVA1KGKnu1.mp3)

Does anyone know how I can achieve this in rails?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `send_file` without a type, it will download the file raw.

Instead, you must specify the type of file so the browser knows how to handle it. For example:

```
def download
  send_file "/path/to/file.mp3", type: "audio/mpeg", filename: "file.mp3"
end
```